# Hadoop, HBase and Apache Nutch compatible versions

Tags: apache, hadoop, web-crawler, hbase, nutch

HBase, and Nutch.
I am trying to integrate the 3 together, but am encountering problems with compatibility.

**I was wondering if anyone knows the which most recent versions of Hadoop, HBase, and Nutch I can use together.**

Any insight is greatly appreciated

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The most recents compatibles versions that you can have now are:

- nutch 2.3.1
- hbase 0.98.17-hadoop2
- hadoop 2.5.2

source: [nutch news](http://nutch.apache.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your response!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Nutch Documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial), It suggests to use `HBase 0.98.8-hadoop` version and if you decide to use another version of HBase please do not be surprised if the stack does not work.